# $C(K,X)$ contains complemented copies of both $C(K)$ and $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

Basically im reading this [article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-11/S0002-9939-2012-11208-0/S0002-9939-2012-11208-0.pdf).

In the introduction the autor claim what the title say, however Im not able to find a reference or  bibliography about it. Could you please give me some references? Thanks in advanced.

Here $C(K,X)$  is the Banach space of all continuous $X$-valued functions that vanish at infinity, in this case we use "$C(K,X)$" instead of  $C_0(K,X)$ when $K$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $C(K,X)$ contains a homeomorphic copy of $X$ is simply to observe the family $(f_x)_{x\in X}$ of constant functions defined by $f_x(k)=x$ for all $k\in K$. Indeed, for $x,y\in X$, we see that $\|f_x-f_y\|_{\infty}=\|x-y\|_X,$ so $x\mapsto f_x$ is an isometry on $X$. This proves the desired with no assumption beyond $X$ being a metric space.

For $C(K,X)$ to contain a homeomorphic copy of $C(K)$ though, it's absolutely essential that $X$ is a vector space (so next time, it's probably a good idea to mention this assumption in your question).  To see that this holds, pick $x\in X\setminus \{0\}$ and define $T_x: C(K)\to C(K,X)$ by $T_x(f)(k)= f(k)x$. Then, for $f,g\in C(K)$, we see that $\|T_x(f)-T_x(g)\|_{\infty}=\|f-g\|_{\infty} \| x\|,$ implying, again, that $T_x$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. Thus, there are *many* copies of $C(K)$ in $C(K,X)$.

Comment: This is pretty concise, Thank you.